# Java Big-O performance

Tags: java, time-complexity

I have a question about the performance of my class project.

I have about 5000 game objects formed from reading a text file.  I have a `Treemap` (called supertree) that holds as its nodes `Treemaps` (mini treemaps I guess). These `nodes/mini treemaps` are action, strategy, adventure, sports, gametitle, etc. Basically game genres and these mini trees will will hold game objects.   So the `supertree` itself will hold probably 8 `nodes/treemaps`.

When I insert a game object, it will determine which `mini tree` it will go to and put it in there.  For example if I insert the game **Super Mario World**, it will check which genre it is and see that it's `adventure`,so **Super Mario World** would be inserted into the `adventure` tree.

So my question is what would be the performance if the question lists all the `action games`, since a Treemap get is O(log n)

First at the super tree it will look for the `Action Node/Treemap`, which will take O(log n).

Then once inside the `Action treemap`, it will do get for all elements which would be o(n log n) correct?

So the total performance of `log n * (n * log n)` is correct?  Which is worst than `o(n)`.

[edit]
Hopefully this clarified my post a bit.

Comment: Editorial: Asking a Big-O question on Stack Overflow: like throwing oil onto the smoldering embers of long-ago college educations ;)

Comment: @user648727 Could you please clarify the layout of your treemaps a little? The supermap contains several genres, and each genre contains a treemap/set of game objects?

Answer (score 5):

While the get on the supermap is O(n_categories), and going through the other map (using an iterator) should be O(n_games). If you n_categories has an upper bound of say 10 (because the number of categories doesn't change when adding new games), you can assume the supermap lookup to be O(1).

Since the submaps can have at most n_games entries (when all belong to the same category), listing all games of type action thus gives you O(n_games). Don't forget that in order to iterate over all entries you don't have to call get() each time. That would be like reading through a book and instead of turning the page to get from page 100 to 101, start counting at the beginning and count to 101...

EDIT: Since the above paragraph stating that if the number of categories is fixed , one can assume the category lookup to be O(1) seems to be hard to accept, let me say that even if you insist category lookup is O(log n_categories), that still gives O(n_games) since the category lookup has to be done only once. Then, you iterate over the result, which is O(n_games). This leads to O(n_games + log n_categories) = O(n_games).

Comment: I don't think it's right to say that the supermap lookup time is O(1). Also, how did you come to that conclusion? So what if the upper bound is 10? log 10 != 1 (base is 2, by the way).

Comment: Because if the number of total categories is bound by a constant, so is the lookup time for a category. And if the lookup time in worst case is bound by a constant, that's what? O(1). Besides that, for O notation it doesn't really matter what base you choose for the logarithm. If you want, you can use 42.

Comment: @Axel That does not mean it will perform in constant time. The BST implementation does not know which element is which. Also, since we're dealing with BSTs, the base is of course 2.

Comment: ... and the base doesn't matter since for all bases, log in one base differs from log in the other base by a constant. Thus log base_1 = k log base_2 and thus by definition O(log base_1)=O(log base_2).

Comment: @someguy: If you have a upper bound of 10 elements, the upper bound for lookup time is the worst case. And in this case, that is a constant. So that gives you O(1).

Comment: @Axel: the edit paragraph would be more convincing if you kept the distinction between n_categories and n_games.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, first thing, your big-O isn't going to change depending on language; that's why people use big-O (asymptotic) notation.

Now, think about your whole algorithm.  You take your outer tree and get each element, which is indeed *O(n<sub>0</sub> lg n<sub>0</sub>)*.  For each of those nodes, you have *O(n<sub>1</sub> lg n<sub>1</sub>)*.  The *lg n*'s differ by only a constant, so they can be combined, and you get *O(n<sub>o</sub>×n<sub>1</sub> lg n)*, or *O(n<sup>2</sup> lg n)*.

Comment: Right, I just figured since I'm writing my project in java and using java's treemap I would put java in the title.

Comment: @Charlie Martin: Compulsive theoretical computer scientist here. I'm not clear on what your various n subscripts represent, and where n_{no_substript} comes from at the end. Please help :)

Comment: It represents being too lazy to work out the whole damn thing rigorously.  You'd really need an n for the number of nodes in the super-tree and another n for each subtree.  So I (implicitly) assumed that each of the subtrees was roughly the same size n1 and that further that we can assume that n1/n0 is bounded above by some constant value, so asymptotically n0==n1.  Conclusion then follows.

Comment: Thanks :) Props for getting SO to math notation using inline HTML. I'm not 100% clear now on what the OP is asking. It seems you are assuming a full walk over both levels of tree; I had assumed a single lookup in the outer tree and a full walk of the inner tree (without counting construction cost of either level). As a final caveat: keep in mind that walking the nodes of a tree is cheaper than repeated element lookups (linear rather than `O(n lg n)`).

Comment: Yeah, I'm an HTML hound; no one ever lets me write LaTeX any more.  But his question assumes a sequence of gets, each of which is O(lg n).  As we're both pointing out, this is probably not optimal for this problem -- hell, if he used a threaded tree he could list all the Action nodes in linear time on the total nodes, or O(n^2) in my terms above and eliminate the log term completely.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of comments regarding the OP's analysis:

I'm assuming you have already constructed your treemaps/sets and are just extracting elements from the finished (preprocessed) in-memory representation.

Let's say *n* is the number of genres. Let's say *m* is the max number of games per genre.

The complexity of getting the right 'genre map' is `O(lg n)` (a single `get` for the supertree). The complexity of iterating over the games in that genre depends on how you do it:

```
 for (GameRef g : submap.keySet()) {
   // do something with supermap.get(g)
 }
```

This code yields `O(m)` 'get' operations of `O(lg m)` complexity each, so that's `O(m lg(m))`.

If you do this:

```
for (Map.Entry e : submap.entrySet()) {
   // do something with e.getValue()
}
```

then the complexity is `O(m)` loop iterations with constant `(O(1))` time access to the value.

Using the second map iteration method, your total complexity is `O(lg(n) + m)`

Comment: Side note: as @Axel points out elsewhere: in this presentation, if you assume that the number of genres `n` is bounded by a constant, then the end result becomes `O(1 + m) = O(m)`.

Comment: Ah thank you, for some reason I thought you were suppose to use "n" for everything in big O and didn't know that you could assign say: n = # of genre and m = # of games in that genre as you did.

Comment: Aren't you evaluating a different problem? His original question is listing all the Action games, which means he has to perform this step n times.  At that point, your analysis and mine are asymptotically the same.

Comment: @Charlie Martin: I am as confused as you are about the actual layout of the trees now. The phrase: "When I insert a game object, it will determine which "mini tree" it will go to and put it in there." seems to suggest that the supertree contains just (a few) genres, while the subtrees contain the game objects specific to that genre.

Comment: @usermanynumbers: You're welcome. I think this is key: you can use as many different symbols as you want, but it's important to define exactly what each symbol means and whether there are any relationships between the symbols.

Comment: I apologize if my wording in my question is confusing.  I haven't wrote the actual project yet, but what I had planned was the SuperTree will probably hold about 8 nodes/treemaps (action, adventure, stratergy, sports, shooter etc.)  And then when I insert an actual game say for example Super Mario World it will check what genre and see that it's adventure, so it would insert it into the adventure tree.  Originally I was thinking of just using an arraylist or something and the performance for list action games or whatever genre would be o(n).  Maybe I should do that instead? =/

Comment: @user648727: It all depends on how you plan to use the data structures. If I were in your position, I would go with what is easiest to code up first, and worry about performance later.

Comment: @phooji: +1 for pointing out the difference of iterating over the keyset + get() and iterating over the entryset.

Comment: @jtn30769 Golly, you know, with the scale of things you're talking about here, just use the Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work; the setup time for something more complicated will probably dominate everything else anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Er, you were right until the last paragraph.

Your total complexity is `O(n logn)`, `logn` to look up the type and `n` to list all the values in that type.

If you're talking about listing everything, it's definitely not `O(n^2 logn)`, since getting all the values in your tree is linear. It would be `O(n^2)`.

Doing the same thing with a flat list would be `O(n logn)`, so you're definitely losing performance (not to mention memory) by using a tree for this.

Comment: Well, except there's no reason either one would be linear time since he's using the same structure for both.  But I agree, a Tree might not be the best choice.

Comment: Not so simple. Big-O means worst case. List all Action games in your map has worst case n because you could have only Action games in your tree, but its not true in real world cenarios. It should be n/GenreSize for each game genre. So, in real world, he should use TreeMaps if he doesnt expect all games in one tree

Comment: Why would a flat list take O(n log n)? Listing everything is O(n), regardless of whether using list or tree - when iterating, you visit each node exactly once, and there are n nodes in total. Remember when iterating over all elements, get is never called - or at least shouldn't be.

Comment: @Plínio Pantaleão: Big-O notation roughly means 'upper bound on the growth of a function', which can be used to describe best case, worst case, or average case running time.

Comment: @Axel, I meant if he wanted his result set grouped by genre. In this case he'd have to sort his list, which is O(nlogn).

Comment: @phooji except usually big-O is used in algorithm analysis for worst-case, and little-o for best case.  So g(x)=O(f(x) means in the limit g(x)/f(x) is bounded by a constant, while g(x) = o(f(x)) means in the limit g(x)/f(x) approaches 0.

Comment: @Charlie Martin: I was just reacting to the phrase 'Big-O means worst case,' which set off my 'Someone on the Internet is Wrong' response. You are right, of course, minus a missing closing paren ;)

Comment: What we need is an EMACS interface for SO.